# Does Windows backup roaming files?

Tags: windows-10, roaming-profiles

Is there hope the get an old version of a file back which is stored in the `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\...` folder? I'm using Windows 10. Is this folder backed up when Windows creates a restore point? I'd say nope, but maybe there is a way...

Comment: System restore has a focus on system files not files within your user profile folder

Comment: I have never found a comprehensive explanation of exactly what a restore point contains in its backup. But you can use Shadow Explorer to see for yourself....https://www.raymond.cc/blog/system-restore-explorer/